# Out of memory handling bitmaps, looking to optimize

Tags: android

I have been having issues loading long images into my app, I often get too large for texture. So i thought I would try to break the images up into slivers and put those together to make the full image, issue is now I am running into an out of memory problem. Here is my code below, any thoughts on what i could do differently to make it more efficient or relieve some of the memory strain? or even if you have a better way?

```
public void tileImage(Bitmap bm){
    Bitmap tile;
    float tileWidth = bm.getWidth();
    float tileHeight =bm.getHeight()/5;

    if(bm.getWidth()<width){
        width=bm.getWidth();
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){

        image = new ImageView(main);

        tile = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                 bm,
                 0, 
                 (int)(tileHeight*i),
                 (int)width,
                 (int)(tileHeight)
                 );
        image.setImageBitmap(tile);
        tiles.addView(image);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is a size of your image? And you are probably testing this on virtual device?

Comment: no i am testing on the s3. And the images come in different sizes as they are user uploaded from other services, some 10k long.

Comment: So thats more than double the texture size

Comment: width * height of image is a size in memory, so by creating this tiles you are doubling the amount you need, did you tried seeng how much is this? Calculate maximum you assume

Comment: Wait, how does this double the size in memory? The overall width and height are the same as the original image?

Comment: Well you already have one main bitmap in your memory then you split it in five subimages, so there you have two of them in your memory, so if you have 10k x 1k image you will get something like 19.53125Mb of memory needed for just this. And how many times do you do this operation. Maybe you don't get rid of used objects.

Comment: just once, I load one image on the screen at any given time and I am sure its garbage collected when i am done

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30444/discussion-between-marko-lazic-and-mr-sir-king-osman)